# How do I hide broken images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my image inside an if statement:

```
if (item.image)
   historyHtml += '<a href=' + item.image + ' class="image" target="_blank"><img src="' + item.image +'" width="111px"/></a>';
```

Comment: Define "broken image"? I don't understand.

Comment: If the item.image is from a broken url. For instance when it shows the read X: http://img807.imageshack.us/img807/8431/brokenimage.png

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the onerror handler. In the inline form, it looks like this:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" onerror="this.style.display='none';" />
```

Comment: Hi Piskvor, thank you very much. I tried that and it throughs me back errors: if (item.image) historyHtml += '<a href=' + item.image + ' class="image" target="_blank"><img src="' + item.image +'" width="111px" onerror="this.style.display='none';" /></a>';

Comment: @jprim : "errors" is annoyingly vague. What exactly happens when you try this?

Comment: @jprim : You're not escaping quotes correctly. Try this: if (item.image) historyHtml += '<a href=' + item.image + ' class="image" target="_blank"><img src="' + item.image +'" width="111px" onerror="this.style.display=\'none\';" /></a>'

Comment: @jprim: "there's an error" "what error?" "an error!" In other words, can you be a bit more specific? Does the syntax error have any more data? On which part of the code it appears to be?

Comment: @jprim: if this is the answer you're looking for, why haven't you accepted it? if you do so, this will help you to get more feedback on your other questions because the peaople can see that they will be rewarded for their help.

Comment: Works on blazor; no need to do fancy stuff

Answer (score 8):

As @piskvor says, actually loading the image in an img tag is the only way of finding out whether the URL is broken or not. The `error` event gets fired if loading fails.

But looking at your code, maybe the opposite approach makes most sense: Hide the `<a>` by default, and show it in the `onload` event of the image.

Abridged:

```
<a href=".." id="image228" style="display: none">
 <img src="..." onload="this.parentNode.style.display = 'block'">
</a>
```

Comment: Hi Pekka, thanks for your help. If I put that piece of code in the link, it still gives me errors.

Comment: Syntax error within Dreamweaver when developing. I got it from Spender below. Thanks.

Comment: @jprim your're welcome.  I'd suggest you familiarize yourself how to escape quotes correctly. Dreamweawver's Syntax highlighting should show you when a string is not correctly escaped

Comment: Much better as this allows you to show the image should you update the src with a valid image